# Why can't you pass a string literal to a function that uses a template argument?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct Node{
    T data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;

    Node(T x) : data(x), left(NULL), right(NULL){}
};

template<typename T>
Node<T>* new_node(T x)
{
    Node<T>* return_node = new Node<T>(x);
    return return_node;
}

int main()
{
    Node<string>* root = new_node("hi"); //error!

    string x = "hi";
    Node<string>* root2 = new_node(x); //OK
}
```

Why can't you use the string literal inside of the parentheses? Are there any simple methods to accomplish the same task without declaring the strings and then creating the nodes, or is this the only way?

Comment: because `T` is deduced as `const char*`, and `Node<const char*>` and `Node<string>` are distinct types

Comment: I think the error message given by compilers would explain.

Comment: If you have C++14, you may try `"hi"s`.

Comment: When you get a compiler error, *post it!*

Answer (score 7):

`T` is deduced to `const char*`, so will be returned `Node<const char*>*`, but you cannot assign it to `Node<string>*`

You can create a temporary:

```
new_node(std::string("hi"));
```

Or you can call `new_node` with explicit qualification:

```
new_node<std::string>("hi");
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why can't you pass a string literal to a function that uses a template argument?

You can, you're not reading the compiler error message properly.

This compiles fine:

```
new_node("hi");
```

But this doesn't:

```
Node<string>* root = new_node("hi"); //error!
```

So the problem is clearly not passing string literals to template functions.